# jQuery - Reorder list by changing textbox value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to reorder a `ul` using a textbox value.

Start with a `ul`....

```
<ul id="ItemList">
    <li> <some text>  <input id="Text1" type="text" value="1" /></li>
    <li> <some text>  <input id="Text2" type="text" value="2" /></li>
    <li> <some text>  <input id="Text3" type="text" value="3" /></li>
    <li> <some text>  <input id="Text4" type="text" value="4" /></li>
</ul>
```

Then if I change the value of `Text4` from `4` to `2` the list will reorder itself while changing the value of `text2` & `3` to `3` & `4` respectively.

I suspect I'm not the first person to have to do this, so if there's pointers available.

I'm not finding anything specific here, but I may not be searching right.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: show us some jquery you have written?

Comment: So, you want to change the text of other textboxes if you change value in one of the tb? Also, is it static list or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to do this (without error checking):

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    var start = $(this).index('input');
    var target = $(this).val() - 1;
    if (target < start) $(this).parent().insertBefore($('li').eq($(this).val() - 1));
    if (target > start) $(this).parent().insertAfter($('li').eq($(this).val() - 1));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dvjXt/)**

Note that is you want to renumber the inputs after the change, add this line to the end of the function `$('input').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).index('input')+1)});`

Comment: That works well for the ordering, but he wants it to also update the values all the way up and down the chain.  It'll need a second function for that (probably best run immediately after the first).  Also doesn't work for copy/paste, and works oddly with two-digit numbers.

Comment: @BenBarden - Does the code in the note of my answer address your concern about the update? I'm unsure of what you'e referring to. As for copy/paste and two digit numbers, that's all minor details once the main ordering is satisfied.

Comment: Fair enough - the onkeyup kibitz is just a kibitz.  Might still be better as an onchange rather than an onkeyup.  Other than that, yeah - it pretty much covers it.  I haven't tested and can't tell you if that works to do what it's trying to do, but it looks like you have all the moving parts you need.